# Deleting optional fields in DAO models

Tags: scala, rest, api, playframework, patch

I have find a way to update database models from http requests as below;

```
case class DatabasePerson(
  id: Int,
  name: Option[String],
  surname: String
)

case class PersonUpdateRequest(
 name: Option[String],
 surname: Option[String]
) {
  def update(databasePerson: DatabasePerson) = databasePerson.copy(
    name = name.orElse(databasePerson.name),
    surname = surname.getOrElse(databasePerson.surname)
  )
}
```

with this way i am able to update the only sent fields from the client. Which i believe sending only the updated (or touched) fields to the api preferred way in technologies such as react.

My problem starts if a person needs to delete an optional field from the db. In the example it can be the `name` value

Only way comes to my mind is expecting an invalid value, such as `""` maybe. So adjusting the update model for such agreement would be something like below;

```
case class PersonUpdateRequest(
  name: Option[String],
  surname: Option[String]
) {
  def update(databasePerson: DatabasePerson) = databasePerson.copy(
    name = if (name.exists(_.isEmpty)) None else name.orElse(databasePerson.name),
    surname = surname.getOrElse(databasePerson.surname)
  )
}
```

this was only for string but i also have dates, numbers or complex models. And as you can see it is a bit tedious to write for all the fields.

I am using play framework for validation, so there is a mapper like this for the update request;

```
object PersonUpdateRequest {
  lazy val map = mapping(
    "name" -> optional(text),
    "surname" -> optional(text)
  )(apply)(unapply)
}
```

What would be the preferred way to delete optional fields on update methods.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll normally handle this in the model. I don't know what library you're using but with `anorm`, you can pass an `Option` and it will update with the column as null if `Option` is `None`

Comment: i see, but such behaviour is something breaks the "send only updated fields" motto. If a person only sends `name:"John"` in the json payload the bound model will be `name=Some("John"), surname=None`. In my case i don't want to nullify surname (which i cannot already since it is a mandatory field), i only want to update name field which is sent. This behaviour is very similar to react and redux form libraries i believe which helps frontend development.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. Not sure if there's a preferred way but I came across this earlier and rolled a new method to generate a `List[String]` of "set x = 'Y'", for every value of type `Some(v)`. Then appended the result to an update query string with a `.mkString(", ")`

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this that would fit your data model is to add an other level of `Option` on your option:

```
case class PersonUpdateRequest(
 name: Option[String],
 surname: Option[Option[String]]
)
```

so you can have those cases:

```
surname == Some(Some("foo")) // set surname to "foo"
surname == Some(None) // set surname to None == delete the value in the db
surname == None // do not update
```

This would imply to use a custom mapper. This might work with a custom json reader `Reads[Option[Option[T]]`. Something like:

```
JsUndefined => None
JsNull => Some(None)
JsString(value) => Some(Some(value)
```

But I'm not sure about how to use it with a `Form`